# Time categorization in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column in pandas dataframe called as TIME.

It looks like this.

```
1:00AM to 2:00AM
2:00AM to 3:00AM
```

and so on, till of the whole day.

I need to make a column called as Time_Shift and divide the time in morning, afternoon, night, evening. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Hi @barkatkhan take some time to review what an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and consider editing your post to include the missing components.  As it stands and in my opinion, this question isn't very clear.

Comment: You need to define at which time the part of the day changes, make a function that format "X:00 to Y:00" to "Y" and a function that take that Y as parameter and test the part of the day. The result is Time_shift. Try to do that and come to us if you have problem,